# Routing not working in angular.js - No console or syntax errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, dependencies

I am unable to understand why the routing isn't working. 
I've checked many times for syntax errors or misspelling but that doesn't seem to be the case. I also checked the console and it returns nothing. Doesn't appear to be any issues.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

// Main Controller 
app.controller("controller", function($scope) {
  $scope.search = {};
});

// Routing
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  console.log("working");
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    controller: "controller",
    templateUrl: "templates/listings.html"
  }).when('/login', {
    controller: "controller",
    templateUrl: "templates/login.html"
  })
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <title>logo</title>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <!-- ANGULAR FILES -->

  <!-- Angular.js -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>

  <!-- ngRoute Script -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.js"></script>

  <!-- Route -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="routes/route.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular App  -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

  <!-- Json Data -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>

  <!-- ======================================================================->


 <!-- Index CSS ( Mainly All The CSS) -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

  <!-- Login CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">




  <!-- Montserrat -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- Open Sans -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- neutron -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Neuton' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- Lato -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


</head>


<body ng-controller="controller">

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div ng-include="'includes/navbar.html'"></div>

    <!-- NG VIEW -->
    <div ng-view></div>

    <div class="footer">
      <!-- footer content goes here -->
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if you use router you don't need to declare controller in html. so try to remove ng-contoller from <body> tag

Comment: @Denis Angular supports controller inheritance.

Comment: it might be good to start with a cdn version of ngRoute, to make sure you are using the same version. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-route.js

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. Currently you are just loading the page, without any change in the URL, so the angular router doesn't do anything.

Basically you need to add default route by having `.otherwise` to your `$routeProvider` which will redirect to `/` default page.

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    controller: "controller",
    templateUrl: "templates/listings.html"
})
.when('/login', {
    controller: "controller",
    templateUrl: "templates/login.html"
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
```

> > Make sure you have same version of angularjs & angular-route

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zmkd71e7/3/) Thanks to @Denis for creating Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I did what you said and changed my code to the above, but the problem still persists.

Comment: @ChristianL it should work..could you create a plunkr/fiddle?